# How to set responsive footer with bootstrap and responsive

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

Any one who can help me. I want to make the footer of my website to be responsive using bootstrap and custom css.

Please help me the output I require is like these two in the bottom **Desktop** and **Mobile** ready.
Please help me to solve thise

**Desktop**
[image]

**Mobile**
[image]

Here is my current code

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <footer>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h3 >Connect With Us</h3>
      <div class="border-bottom"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="row padding-top-15px">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required />
     <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required />
     <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="btn swatch-1"> 
     <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#invitefriendModal" class="btn">Refer a Friend</a>
   </form>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 conl-xs-12"> 
   <div class="footer-social">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank" >Legal</a> <span>Accreditation Number</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900');
    body {
      font-family: Open Sans, Arial;
      }
    .btn.swatch-1{background-color: #20b8cd;color: #fff !important;}
    .btn{font-size: 1em;line-height: 1.6em;border-radius: 0.2em;border:none;padding: 0.3em 2em;}
    footer{
        padding: 2% 4% 1%;
        color: #fff;
        background: #1b1b1b;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }
    placeholder{
        padding:0px;
        color:#fff;
    }
    footer input[type="text"],input[type="email"]{
        background-color:transparent;
        border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
        border-top:none;
        border-left:none;
        border-right:none;
        margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
        font-family:Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size:1.2em;
        color:#fff;
    }
    footer input[type="email"]{
        margin-right:10px;
    }
    footer a {
        margin: 0 1em;
        white-space: nowrap;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 2em;
    }

    footer small {
        display: block;
        margin: 1em 1.7em;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        opacity: 0.4;
    }

    footer .socials i {
        margin: 0em 0.1em;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        line-height: 1.6;
        display: block;
    }

    footer .socials {
        border: 1px solid #fff !important;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 2em;
        padding: 0;
    }

    footer a.btn {
        border: 1px solid #fff !important;
        text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    footer .btn {
        text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    footer h3{
        text-transform:uppercase;
        
    }
    footer h3:after{
        height:5px;
        width:60px;
        background-color:#03d1c1;
        margin-bottom:10px
        
    }
    footer .footer-social .fa {
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 15px;
      width: 35px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 0px 2px;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }

    footer .footer-social .fa:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .fa-facebook {
      background: #3B5998;
      color: white;
    }

    .fa-twitter {
      background: #55ACEE;
      color: white;
    }

    .fa-google {
      background: #dd4b39;
      color: white;
    }

    .fa-linkedin {
      background: #007bb5;
      color: white;
    }

    @media (max-width: 575.98px) {

    footer {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    footer h3{
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1.8em;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    footer .border-bottom{
        height: 5px;
        max-width: 100px;
        background-color: #46b8cd;
        /* border-bottom: none; */
        border-bottom: none !important;
        margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    }
    footer .footer-social{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    footer input[type="text"], input[type="email"] {
        margin-top: 10px;
        width:100%; 
    }
    footer .btn {
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;

    }
    footer form{
        text-align: center;
    }


    }
```

Please view the css below  I forgot to include it in the above.

Comment: You can always edit your original post and add more content there. If you put your additional information here as an answer, your post won't be open to more of people as they see this post has been answered.